# In which scripture do Aditi and Diti occur the earliest?

Tags: scripture

The Adityas are considered to be offspring of Aditi and Daityas the offspring of Diti.  What is their background?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aditi appears in the Rig Veda itself. So, that scripture has to be the earliest one.

> aditir dyaur aditir antariksham (1),
>  aditir mAtA sa pitA sa
>   putrah (2),
>  vishve devA aditih pancha janA (3),
>  aditir jAtam aditir
>   janitvam (4).
>
> Aditi is the heaven, Aditi is the mid-world (1); Aditi is the
>   mother, the father and the son (2); She is the all-gods (Viswadeva-s); she
>   is the five peoples (3); Aditi is all that is born and what is yet to
>   be born (4).
>
> **Rig Veda 1.89.10**

Besides this one, there are other Rig Vedic Mantras too where Aditi is mentioned. And, she is mentioned in some Suktas of Krishna Yajur Veda as well.

**Rig Veda 4.2.11** mentions Diti and aditi both (unable to give the Sanskrit Mantra for this one):

> Lavish on us the finite (diti) and guard the infinte (aditi).

Further references from the Atharva Veda:

> **dite putrAnAm** aditeh akArisham ava (1)
>  devAnAm anarmanam (2)
>  teshAm hi
>   dhAm gabhishak samudriyam (3)
>  nainAn namasA paro asti (4) kaschana (5)
>
> I obtain the protection of Aditi and the children of Diti (1), gods,
>   who are vast, and free from littleness (2); their station is deep like
>   the ocean (3), but there is a power beyond them who can be attained by
>   surrender (4); is it not? (5)
>
> **Atharva Veda 7.7.1**

So, earliest references for both Diti and Aditi has to be the Rig Veda.

Comment: Thank you @tickross.  when is the earliest mention of Adityas and Daityas?

Comment: For Aditya it's Rig Veda but not sure about Daitya.. But Asura (as meaning a Daitya) is used in Krishna Yajur Veda many a times. @SK

Comment: @tickross :P ???

Comment: Haha i did not notice earlier that it was Tick :P @Rohit.

Comment: @Rohit. Change if u like the name.. but i don't think Tickross is  any name